# Prevent inserting text at the beginning of a buffer that starts with read-only text

Tags: elisp, text-editing, text-properties

I'm extending an existing Emacs package and I want to make a part of the buffer not editable (read only).  In fact, I want to make only one line in the middle of the buffer editable and I use the following snippet for achieving that:

```
(put-text-property (point-min) point-before-editable-text 'read-only t)
;; (put-text-property point-after-editable-text (point-max) 'read-only t)
```

However, I can still put cursor at the beginning of buffer and insert some text which is not the desired behavior.

How can I prevent insertions at the beginning of the buffer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to (before adding property `read-only`), make the first character have a value that includes `read-only` for property `front-sticky`:

```
(put-text-property 1 2 'front-sticky '(read-only)) ; Do this one first.
(put-text-property (point-min) 50 'read-only t)
```

See the Elisp manual, node [`Sticky Properties`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sticky-Properties.html).
The problem was that although the first char had a non-`nil` property `read-only`, insertion before it did not inherit that property, because `read-only` was not a `front-sticky` property value for the first character.

Comment: I updated the Sticky Properties link as the earlier version with # tag wasn't working on phone.